# how to make font-weight:bold ,if table tbody tr td value greater than 0 without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

make font-weight:bold if table tbody tr td **value greater than 0** without loop using javascript or jquery

Selector is
$(table tbody tr td)
**without $.each**

HTML Sample

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you specify your question more? What should be greater than 0? The amount of td in a tr?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? SHow us your code

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: i am asking if table cell value greater than 0

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman i applied code like this and i feel this code looping highly $("td").each(function () {
            $cell = $(this)
            if (parseInt($cell.text())>0) {
                $cell.css({ "font-weight": "bold"});
            }
        });  i need to code without looping

Comment: So it is only 1 cell to check if it has value greater than 0?

Comment: @LGSon no table having lot of rows and cells and value may 0 or greater than 0

Comment: How is that value set?...Server side or client side?

Comment: @LGSon client side

Comment: @Ammaiyappank Check my answer, using the `.text()` method in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looping, and since values get set client side, you could combine the [`CSS attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr), a pseudo element like `::after` and an attribute selector.

When your client side routine set a value, it does so to the attribute `data-value=""` instead of inside the element itself, and when done like that, you can use this CSS to style the cells

```css
table td {
  background: #eee;
}

table td::after {
  content: attr(data-value);
  padding: 10px;
}

table td[data-value="0"] {
  color: green;
}

table td:not([data-value="0"]) {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td data-value="0"></td>
    <td data-value="1"></td>
    <td data-value="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td data-value="1"></td>
    <td data-value="0"></td>
    <td data-value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ammaiyappank That's great, then consider to accept it as well

Comment: @Ammaiyappank Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Comment: correct answer i follow this css in my project its working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you need a Jquery, make

```
$('table td').attr('style','font-weight:bold;');
```

Comment: i need to differentiate value 0 and  greater than 0 in table if table td value  greater than 0 ,i have to make  font-weight: bold;  and one condition is without loop $.each

Comment: Don't need jQuery... css make better

Comment: You can't operate separately with each TD, as JQuery returns all matched elements. You SHOULD use .each(), to get each element value - i.e. $('table td').each(function(){alert($(this).html() );})

Comment: @Jan without .each i need without looping

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:empty` css selector like this :

```css
#example td{
  background-color: magenta;
  color: #FFF;
}

#example td:not(:empty){
  background: blue;
}

#myTable td:not(:empty){
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not about an empty cell, it is about a value greater than 0.

Comment: @LGSon value greater than 0 or empty is the same just wait the author for confirmation

Comment: If you put the number 0 in a cell, the `:empty` selector won't _think_ it is empty

Comment: <table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table> cell having values like above table values

Comment: i already create table and cells with javascript loop so i feel no need again apply javascript  loop for font-weight:bold

Comment: So apply font-weight on your creating loop !

Comment: @Ammaiyappank just make a correct post with all your code tried so far. Really just look the post ? We are not magicians, we don't know what you want and what you do actually !

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman  already i achieved by jquery .each() loop font-weight:bold

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text()` for retrieve the value and then passing a function that checks the value, returning it in bold in case of greater than 0. 
I think it is the only way to do it **without adding extra attributes** to the HTML you provide us.

Check this snippet.

```js
tds = $('table tr td').text(function(index, text){
  return text > 0 ? $(this).css({"font-weight": "bold"}).text() : text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your Reply i got exact answer by using css like data-value.

Comment: Is a good option ^-^ The only difference with this method is that you don't need to change the html attributes to check the  value that `td` contains. Depends on what situaion, you will not be able to do it with css.

Comment: this answer good my situation of tables  because I have above 50 tables both tables  dynamically  created so I feel no need to loop anyway I got answer and thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution is to use JQuery selector :contains() to get cell text

```js
$('table td:contains("0")').attr('style','font-weight:bold');
$('table td:contains("test")').attr('style','background-color:yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 width=200 value=9>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the table cell bold by using this CSS:

```css
  table tbody tr td {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
```

That will apply an bold effect to text in the table cells. If there's no table cells to show then it'll skip the CSS rule.

Comment: And Where did it check, `td` value is greater than 0

Comment: @AmitKumar it only applies if there is TD's therefore its greater than 0

Comment: It doesn't need to, if the `td` exists the CSS will style it, if it doesn't the CSS is ignored. It achieves the same effect.